# How to use an html form to gather information to create a link

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

I would like to have a html form that will have the user input values, i.e. module ID for a DEMO, desired dimensions of the mask and which environment the demo should be loaded.  Then from hitting submit a new page would pop up with the desired information filling in the rest of the link.

I hope this makes sense, if not I can try to explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a [dynamic web page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page) where the link in the HTML is constructed on the server-side based on the information provided in your form on the previous page.  Some popular dynamic web page languages are JSP, ASP, and PHP.  Note that dynamic web pages have to be hosted on a web server.